# How to reorder array in PHP?

Tags: php, arrays

I need to reorder an array in PHP.

The array:

```
Array
(
    [0] => /riado/?p=1
    [1] => /riado/?p=2
    [2] => /riado/?p=3
    [3] => /riado/?p=4
)
```

How to reorder to:

```
Array
(
    [0] => /riado/?p=4
    [1] => /riado/?p=3
    [2] => /riado/?p=2
    [3] => /riado/?p=1
)
```

I have searched but I can't find much clues. Can you give me some clues on how to achieve this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
$array = array_reverse($array);
```

Will reverse the contents of `$array`, no matter the sort order of the contents.

```
rsort($array);
```

Will sort the array in reverse alphabetical order.

Comment: Not really. This will keep key->value associations. (the result should be usable in same way in most cases though)

Comment: @Mchl Actually, `array_reverse` does not keep key->value associations unless you do `array_reverse($array, true);`

Comment: Thanks for the reply. array_reverse() worked, rsort() not. Best Regads,

Comment: @André Note that with `rsort()` you don't have to assign to the variable afterwards, so `rsort($array);` works, but `$array = rsort($array);` does not. `rsort()` modifies the existing array, `array_reverse()` returns a new array in the opposite order.

Answer (score 4):

```
rsort($arr);
```

That should do the trick

Comment: I think @André needs to reverse the element order, not reverse sorting.

Answer (score 1):

A simple [rsort](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.rsort.php) should produce the results you require if you want to sort the array in reverse order. (If you simply want to swap the elements from first to last, etc. you could of course use [array_reverse](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-reverse.php) or simply iterate over the array from last to first.)

reverse sort example:

```
<?php
 $testArray = array('/riado/?p=1', '/riado/?p=2', '/riado/?p=3', '/riado/?p=4');
 rsort($testArray);
 print_r($testArray);
?>
```

array_reverse example:

```
<?php
 $testArray = array('/riado/?p=1', '/riado/?p=2', '/riado/?p=3', '/riado/?p=4');
 $testArray = array_reverse($testArray);
 print_r($testArray);
?>
```